# Edit a specific key value of an object inside an array of objects (JSON)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to update an object of a JSON array, I created a function in the name of `AlertJSON` with 3 params `$item` and `$key` and also `$newValue`, basically the function should first search in the JSON array for the Object that contains the specific value `Item` in the defined `Key` and then change the value to `$newValue`, in the MySQL statement I used `JSON_EXTRACT` to EXTRACT the object and then apply some changes on the key-value and update the database with the new `JSON`array, but I guess I'm wrong using `JSON_EXTRACT` first I thought `JSON_SEARCH` will be useful but I tried to understand it and I couldn't figure it out with it, I jumped to `EXTRACT` function because I think I understand it enough.

here is what I have tried:-

`AlertJSON` function

```
<?PHP
    public function AlterJSON($item,$key,$newValue){
        if($this->connected === true){
            try{
                $JsonItems = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*]') = :item");
                $JsonItems->bindParam(":item",$item);
                $JsonItems->execute();
                $JSONfetch = $JsonItems->fetchColumn();
                $itemsArray = json_decode($JSONfetch);
                foreach($itemsArray as $Array){
                    $Array[$key] == $newValue;
                    $newArray = json_encode($Array);
                }
                return $newArray;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                if($this->errors === true){
                    return $this->error($e->getMessage());
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

`Method` Call

```
<?PHP 

 $db = new dbConnect('connection');
 $newCall = $db->AlterJSON('fsdfds','name','tst');
 print_r(var_dump($newCall));

?>
```

I get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and the var_dump `NULL`

updated: The Array format:-

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => o4
        [2] => Efexor
        [3] => Eklil
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 30
        [6] => 15
        [7] => Phezer
        [8] => Venlafaxine
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-08-25
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [id] => 1
        [qty] => 15
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => Efexor
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 30
        [company] => Phezer
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [owned-com] => Eklil
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] => o4
        [chemicalcom] => Venlafaxine
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-08-25
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
 )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 2
        [1] =>
        [2] => Efexor
        [3] => Eklil
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 15
        ....etc
```

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT` Returns data from a JSON document. In your code `JSON_EXTRACT` returns the whole array and that is not equal to the string passed as parameter. [DOC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path)

Comment: @EmptyBrain ok then how to work around the statement to get the object as an array?

Comment: Use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains). use like
`SELECT items FROM `bills` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(items, :item,'$[*]')`. if `WHERE` statement true it returns the `items` JSON. Also decode JSON inside the loop

Comment: @EmptyBrain thanks for your reply man, i tried using JSON_CONTAINS and i changed `$JSONfetch` to `fetchAll` and remove the decoding but i get an empty array like this `array(0) { }`